Iframe preventing interaction of other parts of website - how to resolve?
I have a godot game in an HTML (same origin) iframe with a lot of assets exported to the web, which requires a lot of assets and thus has a large loading time. Currently what I am doing is hiding the iframe and showing a few survey questions to the user. While the user fills those questions out, the iframe is to load. Ideally, by the end of the survey, the app is already loaded and the user will feel a seamless experience.
However, this is not what is happening. The problem I am facing is that while the iframe loads while hidden, I cannot interact with other parts of the webpage(ex cannot click buttons or write text) until it is finished - rendering the whole idea useless.
I tried using web workers in the iframe source JS, however it seems like Godot cannot support this. I would have to work with the obfuscated godot code if I ever wanted a chance to fix this issue so that's not ideal.
What can I do to fix this?

Iframes run in the same thread as the parent page, so if you have a slow script, it will slow down the parent page as well.
The best you are likely to be able to do, is to add as many setTimeout or
requestAnimationFrame calls into you game start up code, to allow the parent page some breathing room to run it’s own code.

Thanks! Is there any way I can do this without editing the game web source code? I think I have identified a fetch() statement(which loads the games assets, wasm, etc.?) as responsible for the resources/lag so wondering how I could give that some breathing room.

Is there any way I can run the contents of an iframe within a web worker or something?
Also - I have noticed that if I use a cross-site source this blocking doesn't occur - by any chance do you know why this happens? Will this happen across all browsers(seems to be the case in chrome, firefox).

My guess is cross-domain is being run in a separate thread on these browser. Their is nothing in the spec to say they have to do that, but if it works in Chrome, FireFox and Safari then your good as every browser is based on one of those three.

WebWorkers are of no help here, ServiceWorkers might be useful, but I think that is a long shot. If crossxdomain fixes this, then that is the way to go.

Thanks for your help here. Cross-domain seems to work only on desktop - on mobile it seems like iframes are run on the same thread :(

I guess the leaves trying to insert setTimeout(0) then, sorry can’’t be of more help.

One last idea, have a look at the sandbox attribute on the iframe.
